# How to get social media icons back on Odoo website?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I accidentally deleted the social media icons on odoo website. I wanted to know how to get it back on website.?

Anyone has any idea on it?

Comment: From where have you deleted the icons?

Comment: by editing the website itself. front end

Comment: anyone has an idea to get it back

Comment: did you tried updating the website module?

Comment: yes i tried, but no effect

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i got it back by editing the HTML editor

Answer (score 0):

I can speak to Odoo 10e (is is a couple of years after original question).

As Admin, login to Website and from the menu choose CUSTOMIZE from the menu.  Then switch on the "AUTOMATIC FOOTER" slider.

This presumes that you have entered Social Media information in WEBSITE ADMIN/CONFIGURATION/SETTINGS/SOCIAL MEDIA.

This is the built-in way to display your Social Media icons in Odoo 10e.